# Adding collection retsults to view and template

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-views

I am using backbone to connect to a 3rd-party api.  I am getting data back, but I'm having a hard time figuring out how to display the data.

The API returns an object that contains an array of video recordings.  I can see the object in my browser console, but I can't figure out how to display in an html template via backbone.

Here is my code:

```
           var RecordingCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
               url: '/api/camtasia',
               parse: function (resp) {
                 return JSON.parse(resp);
               },
           });

           var recordingCollection = new RecordingCollection();

           return Backbone.View.extend({
            className: 'camtasiaRender',
            template: _.template(tmpl, null, { variable: 'ctx' }),

            render: function () {
                recordingCollection.fetch();
                console.log('recordings: ', recordingCollection);           
                this.$el.html(this.template, recordingCollection);
                return this;
            }
    });
});
```

Here is a screenshot of the console that shows there is data in there:

```
recordings:  
child {
    length: 0,
     models: Array[0],
     _byId: Object,
     models: Array[0]
        0: Backbone.Model
            Attributes: Object
            attributes: Object
            odata.metadata: "http://SOM_camsite/Api/v1/$metadata#ApiKeys"
            value: Array[10]
            0: Object1: Object
            2: Object
            3: Object
            4: Object
            5: Object
            6: Object
            7: Object
            8: Object
            9: Object
            length: 10
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should render your view on `sync` event from Collection.

Your view should listen to collection on `initialize`:

```
var RecordingsView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        this.listenTo(this.collection, 'sync', this.render);
    }
});

var recordings = new RecordingCollection();
var recordingsView = new RecordingsView({collection: recordings});

recordings.fetch();
```

Comment: I will try that.  Thanks!

Comment: that produced an endless loop

Comment: It's just basic principle. You should remove `fetch` from your `render` method of course.